Join one dataframe to multiple dataframes in PySpark
I currently have a dataframe that I have to join with multiple equal dataframes. For instance,
values_df:       codes_1_df:         codes_2_df:         codes_n_df:
| ID | value |   | code | cvalue |   | code | cvalue |   | code | cvalue |
| -- | ----- |   | ---- | ------ |   | ---- | ------ |   | ---- | ------ |
| 1  | 000   |   | 0001 | 87f    |   | 0006 | df3    |   | .... | ...    |
| 2  | 111   |   | 0002 | 59d    |   | 0007 | f2r    |   | .... | ...    |
| 3  | 222   |   | 0003 | 111    |   | 0008 | dfd    |   | .... | ...    |

And I would like to get as a result:

| ID |
| -- |
| 2  |

I would like to know what is the best way to get the joined table, knowing that:

There could be multiple 'codes' dataframes.
The 'codes' dataframes might not have any value to join (like codes2_df in the example above)
I just need to retrieve the IDs from the values_df

What I've tried is:
codes_combined_df = reduce(DataFrame.unionAll, [
    codes_1_df,
    codes_2_df,
    codes_n_df
])

df = values_df.join(codes_combined_df, values_df.value == codes_combined_df.cValue).drop('value', 'code', 'cvalue')

Is there a more efficient or more elegant way to write this?

Hello, could you post the full code that you have tried? So anyone can help you more easier

If all we want is a list of the distinct IDs, we can just do the following:
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

combined_ids = values_df.select(f.col("ID"))

code_dfs = [
    codes_1_df,
    codes_2_df,
    codes_n_df
]

for code_df in code_dfs:
    combined_ids = combined_ids.unionByName(
        code_df.select(f.col("code").cast("int").alias("ID"))
)

ids_df = combined_ids.distinct()

Then ids_df will contain the IDs as you requested in the question.
PS: I added some data casting due to the apparent discrepancy in your example, feel free to ignore if it isn't relevant.
